# Why doesn't the program work when I use a void** pointer instead of int**?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I was trying to write a program for printing one multi-dimensional matrix with  unspecified dimensions and I observed that the program doesn't run when I write `void**` rows. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printf("The size of matrix\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int **rows; //it doesnt work with void 
    rows = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rows[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             rows[i][j] = i + j;
             printf("%d", rows[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't run or doesn't compile? How compiler would know how to access `rows[i][j]` if type of `**rows` is `void`?

Comment: I mean, generally if you take a working program and make arbitrary changes for no reason, the result won't work.  Is there a reason why you think `void **` *should* work?  Then someone might be able to explain where you're mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

> doesn't run when I write void**

It is because you can't dereference the `void` pointer as it is not referencing any type.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't the program work when I use a `void**` pointer instead of `int**`?

`void` is, by specification, an incomplete type that cannot be completed (C 2018 6.2.5 19). It is largely intended to facilitate working with pointers in generic ways.

When `rows` is declared to be `void **`, then the type of `rows[i][j]` is `void`. In `rows[i][j]=i+j;`, you attempt to assign a value to a `void` object.

To assign a value to an object, the compiler needs a complete type for the object. It needs to know how the object is represented in memory so that it can write bytes representing the value in memory. When the type is `void`, it is not complete, and there is no information about how to represent a value in memory.

The C standard specifies constraints for the type of the left operand of an assignment, and `void` does not satisfy these constraints, so the compiler issues a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 0):

The void pointer indicates that the pointer is basically empty- and thus, it is capable of holding any data type address in the program.
But to access the data further typecast to other data types is required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printf("The size of matrix\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    void **rows; //it works now
    rows = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rows[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            *((int *)(*rows + i) + j) = i + j;
            //  rows[i][j] = i + j;
            printf("%d", *((int *)(*rows + i) + j));
        }

        printf("\n");        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps expand the answer to include *why* faffing around with an unnecessary (and inefficient) re-cast is a solution, over declaring the appropriate type in the first place.  While it *might* ‘work’ it’s certainly not a solution; and certainly more confusing to read.